# Interrupt arduino when a particular value is read by a ultrasonic range finder

Tags: arduino

I'm new to arduino and currently using Arduino Uno. I need to interrupt arduino when a specific value is read by ultrasonic range finder. Since i'm entirely new to this i dont know anything on interrupts in arduino, I'm expecting a clear answer.

Comment: Why you have to "interrupt"? If you mean to stop, then ok, otherwise you can't trigger a real "interrupt" from software. Anyway instead of using the interrupts (you can't setup two interrupts on the same pin!) use the library [NewPing](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/NewPing). It's really easy to use and can give you good results

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using SC-RS04 module, because that is what Arduino hobbyst usually use.

Acccording to the [datasheet](http://www.robotshop.com/media/files/PDF/datasheet-sen026.pdf), the distance is encoded in the duration of an echo pulse Arduino will recive from the module.

To calculate the width of the pulse you will need to set up two interrupts.

One is RISING interrupt for catching the start of the pulse. The interrupt handler will use the [millis](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Millis) function to record the time of the start of the pulse.

The other is FALLING interrupt for recording the end of the pulse. This interrupt handler will use millis function and previously recorded time to calculate the durantion and from that duration it will calculate the distance. If the distance is below a specific threshold, it will call your logic.

Read [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AttachInterrupt) about setting up interrupts.

Comment: It is HC-SR04, i suppose. But anyhow the procedure is same, Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: Sorry, but... How can you attach TWO interrupts on the same pin? Or are you suggesting to use two interrupt pins to detect the two conditions?

Comment: Yes, these are two interrupts. One is RISING and the second is FALLING.